# Como mostar as alterações feitas em uma revisão do SVN?

Tags: linha-de-comando, svn

Eu tenho o número de uma revisão no [svn](/questions/tagged/svn). Como eu faço (em linha de comando) para mostrar as alterações que foram feitas no nessa revisão?

Até onde consegui:

> svn log -r XXXXXX

Mas dessa forma ele só mostra o texto do *Commit*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente usar `--verbose` junto do comando que você usou:

```
svn log --verbose -r XXXX
```

**Referência:**

[simple command to show changes made in a revision](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2008-01/0313.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

```
svn log --verbose -r <numeroDaRevisao>
```

Lista com os caminhos de diretório completos:

```
svn diff --summarize -r<revisaoFinal>:<revisaoInicial>
```